# How to handle concurrent data modification mess and merge in a web service (Optimistic/Pessimistic Locking)?

Tags: java, postgresql, asynchronous, concurrency, spring-jdbc

I have a web service and couple of background-running asynchronous services (for long-running processes of data gathering) which are using same DAO library and shared data source. DAO library implemented using Spring JDBC Template. RDBMS is PostgreSQL.
It's not rare when the web service and the asynchronous services are concurrently modifying same rows in one table through DAO and I have inconsistent data as result.
For example I have "state" field in an entity which can take the value: 1 - paid, 2 - unpaid.
 

Sometimes I have situations like this:

- transaction #1: The web service are modifying the "state" value from
  1 to 2 to row with ID = 1.
- transaction #2: At same time a asynchronous service are grabbing some
  data from some endpoints and modifying another fields of row with ID
  = 1. But "state" field sill hold 1. It doesn't know that the "state" value was changed from 1 to 2 in transaction #1.

As result I have "state" equals to 1 although it must be 2. It also works controversial. Some times a asynchronous service changes "state" field and the web service doesn't know about this change and again create mess in data. It happens not only with state field of course.

I have two options:

1. Use pessimistic SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.
    But it isn't fit for me
   because the web service very often get parts of rows from table. It
   can't wait for long time period while a asynchronous service hold
   lock because performance here is critical.
2. Use optimistic locking. The "Version" field and so on.
    But I can't just rollback
   changes in case of optimistic locking failure because this changes
   have to be merged. Some times I can't just repeat operation because of atomic operations in another systems which isn't part of spring jdbc transaction.

May be exists some patterns to handle cases like that to merge data?

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: It is not exactly a duplicate, because this question is about the problem of a long running operation and multiple shorter ones on same database. This point is **not** addressed by the other question nor any of its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use as a *rule of thumb* - mean that it can be adapted for special use cases ...

- inside one single transaction (and I have one single write transaction per request) : pessimistic locking because all such transactions are short (they really have to be) and so the delay for obtaining the lock is acceptable and better than having to rollback and retry in case of exception (*)
- between two different request processing (the GET to show a form and the POST/PUT that submits it) : optimistic locking, because I do not want to keep true database locks for a long period of time

It is quite simple, coherent, and I only rethink about that if things really go wrong.

The only use case for optimistic locking inside one single transaction is if you have a really high number of concurrent requests, and each user updates it own data so the risk of contention if small - but you only gain the time of the *lock* phase, because the probability of waiting for the lock is equally low.

(*) if you get an optimistic lock exception, you have to rollback the transaction, and either you can allow to simply report an error, or you have to retry it a number of times.

EDIT:

If I have correctly understood, your problem is that you have one long running batch operation and short web service requests.

IMHO there are three ways to solve that, but there is currently not enough information to choose which is the best for your use case

- use many short transactions in your batch. That way you can use either optimistic locks (with retry) if the probability of simultaneous updates is low or pessimistic locks if you do not have too much simultaneous web service requests. It is the simplest way, but may not be usable if your business rules require that the batch uses one single transaction.
- use pessimistic locks in batch and web service requests, but with a short timeout for web service part. That way if you acquire the lock in a web service, you are sure no batch is modifying same value and can safely commit. Once you have the lock in batch, you are sure no web service will modify the value until the commit. And if a web service cannot get the lock, just return an error to caller. The only requirement there is that the client of the web service can retry its request later.
- do not immediately execute the transactions submitted by the web services but enqueue them, and process them all at the end of the batch operation. This way you are sure that the web services return immediately and that no concurrent update can occur. But you must provide a mechanism to allow client of web service to later consult the result of their requests if they may be rejected, and anyway it supposes requests can be deferred. That would work fine for bank account deposits, need feedback for retrievals, and could not be used for booking seats in a plane.

Comment: Thanks for answer. As I wrote in question problem more complicated then chose between optimistic and pessimistic lock. Try to explain in the example. A async service starts do work and select from database batch of rows. Then it call some web services to get some data to enrich this rows. The web service calls takes long period of time. And after all updates the service saves the rows. I have long transaction here and 3rd party web services calls aren't part of the transaction. If I will repeat this calls then I'll get data duplication in 3rd party systems.

Comment: @Ivan : Oups I did not notice it at first, but it looks like your problem is as follow : you have *on same database* modifications that can come from web services with short transactions and from batches with long running transactions. Can you confirm that and it yes say how long do the batches run ?

Comment: Yes, I confirm. I have 2 problems here: 
1) I have 3 async services are batch or one-by-one updating the rows in same table using 3rd party services every day and enough often in parallel. An interval between selecting the rows and updating them is too long. From 10 seconds up to 10 minutes because of very slow interaction with 3rd party services. 
2) The payment transactions which are changing state of the rows some times in same table.

Seems like first solution will be a good fit for me, I'll try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go with optimistic locking.. And do not rollback when the update fails due to version mismatch.. Instead retry until it succeeds.
You may have an upper limit for number of retries..

Comment: Unless you use a savepoint, rolling back the transaction is the only option you have in Postgres. Once there was an error in a transaction you can not "just continue"

Comment: I can't just rollback. For example. Service A select some rows and dealing with them some long-running process with batch of updates to the rows at the end. Meanwhile service B is doing payment for one of these rows which already service A is using. Now we have situation that Service B changed state from unpaid to paid and commit changes to database, but service B doesn't know about changes and will just override state from paid to unpaid when it will commit his own changes. Both services are using 3rd party services and I can't repeat the operations again. I need some kind of merge.